# How to tell main thread that part of thread job is done

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it true that notify works only after thread is finished? In code below I can't get notification until I comment while (true). How to tell main thread that part of thread job is done?

```
public class ThreadMain {
    public Thread reader;
    private class SerialReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);                
                    synchronized(this) {
                        System.out.println("notifying");
                        notify();
                        System.out.println("notifying done");
                    }                
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    ThreadMain() {
        reader = new Thread(new SerialReader());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ThreadMain d= new ThreadMain();    
        d.reader.start();
        synchronized(d.reader) {
            try {    
                d.reader.wait();
                System.out.println("got notify");
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }    
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Register and notify listeners.

Comment: [This might be worth reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916398/communicating-between-two-threads).

Comment: Please note that you are calling notify on the instance of class SerialReader, not the instance of class Thread. Thus d.reader.wait() waits on another object's monitor than you use in the worker.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid using `wait` and `notify` with the newer versions of Java, as they're difficult to get right.  Try using something like a `BlockingQueue` instead

```
public class ThreadMain {
    public final BlockingQueue<Boolean> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private class SerialReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);                
                    System.out.println("notifying");
                    queue.offer(Boolean.TRUE);
                    System.out.println("notifying done");            
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    ThreadMain() {
        reader = new Thread(new SerialReader());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ThreadMain d= new ThreadMain();    
        d.reader.start();
        try {    
            d.queue.take(); // block until something is put in the queue
            System.out.println("got notify");
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: If one really want to use concurrency classes, a better fit would be CountDownLatch or Semaphore. But BlockingQueue could be nice for incremental notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when the `Thread t` completes, call `t.join()` in the calling Thread. This will block until `t` has finished its `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

As user oddparity noted in the comments, you are calling `wait()` and `notify()` on different objects. A possible fix for this would be to make your `SerialReader` extend `Thread` rather than implement `Runnable` and then assigning `reader` to be a new instance of the `SerialReader` directly. :

```
public class ThreadMain {
    public Thread reader;
    private class SerialReader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);                
                    synchronized(this) {
                        System.out.println("notifying");
                        notify();
                        System.out.println("notifying done");
                    }                
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    ThreadMain() {
        reader = new SerialReader();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ThreadMain d= new ThreadMain();    
        d.reader.start();
        synchronized(d.reader) {
            try {    
                d.reader.wait();
                System.out.println("got notify");
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }    
        }        
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Runnable` with `wait()`/`notify()` you can do it this way :

```
public class ThreadMain {

  public Thread reader;

  private class SerialReader implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
      Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();

      while (true) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(3000);
          synchronized (thisThread) {
            System.out.println("notifying");
            thisThread.notify();
            System.out.println("notifying done");
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ThreadMain() {
    reader = new Thread(new SerialReader());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadMain d = new ThreadMain();
    d.reader.start();
    synchronized (d.reader) {
      try {
        d.reader.wait();
        System.out.println("got notify");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: …but instead of teaching the OP about extending Thread (which only diverts from more useful alternatives), we should point out that there are better patterns/classes in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) than `wait/notify`.

Comment: For some reason it is mor convenient to me is to have Runnable. Is it possible somehow to have thread handle from runnable and using it to make Synchronized?

Comment: I must use java 1.4, so there is no possibility of using java.util.concurrent

Comment: in that case, using Thread#join is most appropriate. Not sure why anybody would still use Java 1.4, though.

Comment: You can do it with `Runnable` if you really want to. See edit.