# Events between threads in java

Tags: java

I have two threads created from the same process that are servers in two different server/client chats. What i want is this : When a specific event happens in one server (like a button press) that thread has to notify somehow the other thread. Is there a way to use java events for this purpose ? Is there an alternative?

**EDIT:**
Is there another way to do it other than checking a variable inside method run all the time ? I was thinking something like signals in C for example where you can handle signals asynchronously with the use of signal handlers.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916398/communicating-between-two-threads

Comment: Please if you want to downvote my question then it's fine , but it would be helpful to write in the comments the reason you do that so I can understand and perhaps make better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Event bus / Message Bus

An event bus (aka message bus) is a simple way to let objects indirectly invoke code on one another without explicitly referencing one another.

Some objects register their interest in certain types of events/messages by signing up with a message bus object. Objects generating such events/messages publish them by calling the message bus. The message then iterates through all the registrants to invoke a certain method tagged with a certain annotation.

[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) provides such an event bus. But I don't recommend it because they inexplicably use strong references. That means you must be rigorous in always de-registering any subscribing objects that should otherwise qualify for garbage collection.

I do recommend using the [MBassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador) project. Be default it uses weak references. And you can easily call it asynchronously.

## Message Queue

A [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) is another way to let objects anonymously communicate with one another. But a message queue is different from an event bus in a few ways.

- A message queue usually has a payload of a short piece of text, not an object.
- A message queue is passive, queueing up messages and waiting for other objects/systems to inquire for fresh messages. An event bus is active in that it invokes a method on each of the registered subscriber methods.
- A message queue is usually external to an app, a separate process, meant for separate systems to communicate. However, you can have a message queue within your app if you wish.